# discord.js argument separator issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, image-manipulation, jimp

I have been trying to get my args to work and they do but I am not sure how to make a separator for it so I don't have to use the command twice. Here's my code.

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const Jimp = require('jimp');
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
  name: "cat",
  aliases: [],
  run: async(client, message, args) => {
    //const top = args[0]
    //const bottom = args[1]
    let [top, bottom] = args

    Jimp.read("assets/cat.jpg").then(function(image) {
      Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_32_WHITE).then(function(font) {
        image.print(font, 60, 22, top, 5);
        image.print(font, 60, 350, bottom);
        image.write('output-image.jpg');
      });
    });
    await message.channel.send({
      files: [
        "output-image.jpg"
      ]
    });
    fs.unlinkSync('output-image.jpg');
  }
};
```

And here's the output I get.

[output image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBkYk.png)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what your problem is? To me I don't see any issue with the args. More likely you are doing things out of sync. When you are sending the message you have no guarantee that the file will exist. Also there is no need to create a file at all, you could send a buffer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please elaborate your query and explain the desired output and the errors you are encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to send the file outside of the promise's `.then()` method. When you call `await message.channel.send()` the file is just being read by `jimp` and the `output-image.jpg` is nowhere near ready.

### Use async-await

As your `run()` method is already an async function, you could use async-await to make your code more readable. That way you can get rid of the callbacks and make it easier to follow what's happening and in what order.

### Buffer instead of files

As Skulaurun Mrusal mentioned in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68557548/discord-js-argument-separator-issue#comment121161816_68557548), you don't even need to save the file, you could just send a buffer. Jimp has a [`.getBuffer()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp#writing-to-buffers) method you can use to generate a binary buffer of an image.

You can send this buffer as an attachment. Discord.js has a [`MessageAttachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment) object that accepts a buffer as the first argument. You can send this attachment by passing it to `message.channel.send(new MessageAttachment(buffer))`.

### Accept text longer than a single word

Currently, as your `args` is an array of space-separated strings, you can only add one word as the text on the top and another one as the bottom text. It's probably easier to accept two longer text that's inside double quotes (`"`).

So the command should be used like this:

```js
!cat "This is the text on the top" "And we are down here"
```

You can use a "simple" regex that matches strings that are inside double quotes. In the next example, you can see that `matches` is an array of the two substring inside the double quotes. They include the quotes too, so you'll need to get rid of that with a [`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
let content = '!cat "This is the text on the top" "And we are down here"'
let matches = content.match(/"(.*?)"/g)

console.log({ matches })
```

### Text alignment

At the moment you're using "magic numbers" (60, 22, 350, 5, etc.) to position the text. It won't work and (depending on the text submitted through the command) it will be all over the image, and chances are it will never be centred.

Jimp has different [align modes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp#align-modes) you can take advantage of. To align the text to the centre horizontally, you can use `HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER`, to align to the top, you can use `VERTICAL_ALIGN_TOP`, etc. Make sure to set the max width and max height to the image's width and height. You can get it using [`image.bitmap.width`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp#low-level-manipulation) and [`image.bitmap.height`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp#low-level-manipulation)

### Working code

```js
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const Jimp = require('jimp');

module.exports = {
  name: 'cat',
  aliases: [],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    let matches = message.content.match(/"(.*?)"/g);
    let [topText, bottomText] = matches
      ? matches.map((m) => m.replace(/"/g, '').toUpperCase())
      : args;

    if (!topText)
      return message.channel.send(`Don't forget to add the text you want to print`);

    try {
      let image = await Jimp.read('cat.jpg');
      let font = await Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_64_WHITE);
      let padding = 40;
      let pos = {
        x: 0,
        yTop: padding,
        yBottom: padding * -1,
        maxWidth: image.bitmap.width,
        maxHeight: image.bitmap.height,
      };

      image.print(
        font,
        pos.x,
        pos.yTop,
        {
          text: topText,
          alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
          alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_TOP,
        },
        pos.maxWidth,
        pos.maxHeight,
      );

      if (bottomText)
        image.print(
          font,
          pos.x,
          pos.yBottom,
          {
            text: bottomText,
            alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
            alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BOTTOM,
          },
          pos.maxWidth,
          pos.maxHeight,
        );

      let buffer = await image.getBufferAsync(Jimp.MIME_JPEG);

      message.channel.send(new MessageAttachment(buffer));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      message.channel.send('Oops, there was an error. Maybe try again later?!');
    }
  },
};
```

### Result

[image]

[image]

<sub><sup>The image of the cat is available on [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/photos/gKXKBY-C-Dk).</sup></sub>

Comment: Thank you so much, This actually helped and I now know a little bit more on how this stuff works as I'm a little bit of a noobie. I'm sorry that I didn't mention it before but thank you so much.